# Sencha Touch dynamically render a model

Tags: api, mobile, model, sencha-touch, entity-attribute-value

I have a database structure that is based on EAV model. Each objects has different kind of metafields with different names.

How could I create a Model in Sencha Touch that will be dynamic?

Thanks.

Regards,

Shafqat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing preventing you from creating the Models at run time.

```
function processEAV(attributes, types){

   var modelDef = {
      fields:[]
   }

   for(var i = 0, len = attributes.length; i < len; i++){
      modelDef.fields.push({name:attributes[i], type: types[i]});
   }

   Ext.regModel('NewModel', modelDef);

}
```

You can add all the additional properties that are needed like validations and associations.

This obviously isn't that great as you'll be doing it every time it is loaded.  It may be better to, on the server, output the model definitions whenever they change and just include them into your mobile html document.